# How to setup a dedicated GPU in order to benchmark a CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I want to use second GPU device as a dedicate device under linux, in order  to benchmark a kernel.

The kernel that I am testing  is a SIMD computing kernel without reductions and not X-Server is attached to the GPU, the device is a GeForge GTX-480 so I suppose that the compute capability is 2. Therefore, advanced features as dynamic parallelism and others, are disabled.

using the nvidia-smi utility there are various modes to setup the GPU

```
"Default" means multiple contexts are allowed per device.
"Exclusive Process" means only one context is allowed per device, usable from multiple threads at a time.
"Prohibited" means no contexts are allowed per device (no compute apps).
```

Which is the best mode to setup the GPU in order to obtain a benchmark as faithful as possible?

What is the command that I should use in order to make permanent such setup?

I am compiling the  kernel using the following flags:

```
nvcc --ptxas-options=-v -O3   -w   -arch=sm_20 -use_fast_math -c -o
```

Exist a better combination of flags in order to obtain more help from the compiler to get faster execution times?

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what problem you hope to solve, but you may want to explore the utility of  `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, as explained in this [blog post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/)

Comment: I managed to pick the target GPU using HANDLE_ERROR(cudaSetDevice(1));

Comment: I managed to pick the target GPU using HANDLE_ERROR(cudaSetDevice(1)). I think that it is a programmatic  equivalent to  export the variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.  my question is  related to  what is more appropriated? setup the GPU to a compute-exclusive mode or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is related to what is more appropriated? setup the GPU to a compute-exclusive mode or not.

It should not matter whether you set the GPU to exclusive-process or Default, as long as there is only one process attempting to use that GPU.

You generally would not want to use exclusive-thread except in specific situations, because exclusive-thread could prevent multi-threaded GPU apps from running correctly, and may also interfere with other functions such as profiler functions.

> What is the command that I should use in order to make permanent such setup?

If you refer to the nvidia-smi command line help (`nvidia-smi --help`) or the nvidia-smi man page (`man nvidia-smi`), you can determine the command to make the change.  Any changes you make will be permanent until they are explicitly changed again.